# React TypeScript enum for prop which doesn't need to be imported to be used?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which takes a number prop:

```
const Component = ({ level } : { level: number }) => {
  // stuff
}
```

And is used:

```
<Component level={1} />
```

I want to limit the prop so it can only be 1 or 2. I can do it like this:

```
export enum Levels {
  First,
  Second
}

const Component = ({ level } : { level: Levels }) => {
  // stuff
}
```

And it would be used:

```
<Component level={Levels.First} />
```

However this it's a bit annoying to have to have to import `Levels`. Is it possible to remove this requirement so `Component` can be used as per the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the type `number`, you can use a [numeric literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#numeric-literal-types) in its stead:

```
const Component = ({ level } : { level: 1 | 2 }) => {...}
```